# Implementing context menu to ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I'm trying to make a context Menu for a list.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    content = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    registerForContextMenu(list);
}
```

When it gets to `registerForContextMenu(list);`, I get a run time error.

Another thing, when I am using `android:id="@androidid/list"` in the XML, how do I refer to the list?
I tried ListView `list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);`, but still get an error
registering to the context menu.

Comment: The list is null because you didn't set the content view.

Comment: First Set content View then use findViewByID

Comment: but then i get an error, because i'm using the android:id="@+id/list"
in the xml. When i'm trying to use android:id="@android:id/list" and
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list); , i don't get the error but still no context menu(I did implement the onCreate for it)

Comment: Sorry, it does work with the android.R.id.list, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
 @Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);  

    adapter = new ListviewAdapter(this, month, desc, icons);  
         // set here your listview adapter value
    lview3.setAdapter(adapter);  

    //for context menu
    registerForContextMenu(lview3);

}

//start from here context menu//

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("select");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 3");
}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Action 1") {
        //
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Action 2") {
        //
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Good Luck.